# Running .exe file in Git Bash

Tags: git, git-bash, cloc

I want Git bash to execute a .exe file just by writing `git filename.exe`. Indeed, I've got the cloc.exe file (which counts code lines) and I want to run it from Git Bash instead of from Windows CMD.

Answer (score 1):

For that, your executable needs to be:

- on the `$PATH` (which can be defined in `~/.bashrc`)
- named `git-cloc.exe`

Then you would be able to type, in a git bash session (or even in a CMD, if part of the `%PATH%`):

```
git cloc
```

The idea is: any executable name `git-xxx` allows you to type `git xxx` (as long as it is found in the `$PATH`)